# how to use array in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

How to use array with preg_replace.
I've tried this:

```
function regex($text){
$array = 'replace1','replace2';
$text = preg_replace(
            '#.$array.*#', '', $text );
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Where is your array?

Comment: `'replace1','replace2'` should that be `['replace1','replace2']`, typo?

Comment: If it is static text you can just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an array anywhere in your code. Assigning to a variable with comma-separated values doesn't make an array, you need to call the `array()` function. And you can't interpolate an array into a string (not to mention that variables are only interpolated in double-quoted strings, but you used single quotes).

You need to make an array of regular expressions.

```
function regex($text) {
    $array = array('#replace1#', '#replace2#');
    $text = preg_replace($array, '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/oeFEby)

Comment: But .* not works in preg_replace! Which removes everything.Is there any meaning # in array element ?

Comment: `#` is just the regular expression delimiter.

Comment: I've added a link to a demo.

Comment: What makes this: #a[nt]#
Search for work where contains 'a' with 'nt' then removes.

Comment: That's a simple regular expression. If you don't understand it, you need to read a regexp tutorial, like www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: Why are you asking about `preg_replace` if you don't even know the basics?